# How to send ASCII values greater than 127 to serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

Whenever i send any ASCII value greater than 127 to the com port i get junk output values at the serial port.

```
 ComPort.Write(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only contains 128 possible symbols.
You will need to use a different character set to send anything other than the 33 control characters and the 94 letters and symbols that are ASCII.

To make things more confusing, ASCII is used as a starting point for several larger (conflicting) character sets.
This list is not comprehensive, but the most most common are:

1. [Extended_ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) which is ASCII with 128 more characters in it.
2. [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is ASCII with all characters required to represent all Western European languages.
3. [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is ISO 8859-1 with a few alterations (including printable characters in the 0x80-0x9F range).
4. [ISO 8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) which is the equivalent for Eastern European languages.
5. [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) is also for Eastern european languages, but bears little resemblance to 8859-2.
6. [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) is also derived from ASCII, but has different characters from 128 to 255.

Back to your problem: your encoding is set to ASCII, so you are prevented from sending any characters outside of that character set.  You need to set your encoding to an appropriate character set for the data you are sending. In my experience (which is admittedly in USA and Western Europe) Windows-1252 is the most used.

In C#, you can send either a string or bytes through a Serial Port.  If you send a string, it uses the [SerialPort.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert that string into bytes to send.  You can set this to the appropriate encoding for your purposes, or you can manually convert convert a string with a [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Set the encoder on the com port:

```
ComPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
```

or manually encode the string:

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
byte[] sendBuffer = enc.GetBytes(command);
ComPort.write(sendBytes, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
```

both do functionally the same thing.

---

EDIT:
0x96 is a valid character in Windows-1252
This outputs a long hyphen.  (normal hyphen is 0x2D)

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
byte[] buffer = new byte[]{0x96};
Console.WriteLine(enc.GetString(buffer));
```

Comment: When i changed the encoding from 28591 to Windows-1252 in my application, at the serial port i get junk value for ASCII value 150. For other characters the output is unchanged!

Comment: For values < 127 I would expect output to be unchanged.  For values > 127 it should convert the characters into byte values that can be sent through the serial port.  Can you use the second example of what you're trying to send and what is the "junk value" you're getting?  character 150 in windows-1252 is backtick: `  Is that what you're trying to send?

Comment: The character that i am sending is 0x96 hyphen(-) and what i get at the output is question-mark(?) when using windows-1252.

Comment: Question-Mark ? is the default character .net replaces something with if it is unknown.  If it is replacing that with question mark, then it can't do the encoding.  Can you try my second example where you do the encoding manually and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved when the encoding on the serial port was changed.

```
this.ComPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

Comment: Hmm, no, that code page is missing 0x80 through 0x9F.  Write *bytes* instead of characters.