# Pic ccs 16f84 + rs232 Trouble sending higher values than 0x79 (they become 0x3f)

Tags: serial-port, pic

I´ve some problems trying to send a byte to a PIC via rs 232.

I've already tried it on a physical device, and in proteus as well.

When I try to send a **0x80** value or higher, its just sends a **0x3f**, and I really wonder why.

When I send values between  **0** and **0x79** everything goes fine.

I've used various hyperterminals and my own vbstudio software and all of them return the same...

Here is the code, it just makes an echo of the received value and stablishes it on PORTB.

```
 #include <16F84.h> 
    #fuses XT,NOWDT,NOPROTECT 
    #use delay(clock=4000000)  
    #use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_A1,rcv=PIN_A0,bits=8)  
    unsigned int rx; 

    void main (){  
    set_tris_b(0b00000000);
    set_tris_a(0b00000001); 

      while(true){ 
         rx=getc();    
    printf("%x\r\n", rx);  
     output_b(rx);  
      }}
```

After all this data I just can think that maybe, somehow, its gonna be something on the fuses? It is really wierd.

Can somebody help me please, thanks for reading! :)

Comment: Are you checking this with a protocol analyzer?  Has the sending end set up its bits and parity correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving an ASCII ? (0x3F) when the input is greater than 127 sounds suspiciously like an encoding problem on the transmitting side, not an issue with the PIC.

Refer to "[How to send ASCII values greater than 127 to serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503354/how-to-send-ascii-values-greater-than-127-to-serial-port)" for ways to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay, the problem was on the vb.net side, i found this and it helped me a lot.

Extended SerialPort Windows Forms Sample

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Extended-SerialPort-10107e37

The problem was i was sending ASCII instead raw hex bytes
Thanks to all